# How to activate the cursor for a fabric js IText?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'd like to be able to add text to the canvas and have it go directly into editing text mode where the cursor is visible and you can start typing.

So far I've got this code that adds the text and sets it as active, but I'm not sure on how to go to the edit text mode.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

```
    var fabicText = new fabric.IText('Click to change Text', { left: 100, top: 100 });
   fabicText.set({ fill: getSelectedColorText() });
   _fabicCanvas.add(fabicText);

  _fabicCanvas.setActiveObject(fabicText);
```

Comment: Did you find solution to show the caret?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to use `enterEditing()` method and then set focus on hiddenTextArea like this

```
fabicText.enterEditing();
fabicText.hiddenTextarea.focus();
```

---

```js
var _fabicCanvas;

$(function () {
    _fabicCanvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    var fabicText = new fabric.IText('Click to change Text', {
        left: 100,
        top: 100
    });
    _fabicCanvas.add(fabicText);
    fabicText.set({ fill: 'blue' });
    _fabicCanvas.setActiveObject(fabicText);
    fabicText.enterEditing()
    fabicText.hiddenTextarea.focus();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/v1.4.5/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" class="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, just to add doing the above sets the cursor at the beginning of text box, for me adding `fabricText.selectAll()`  after focus worked a treat - it means users can immediately start typing and replace all existing text :)

Comment: At least with my version (1.5), `fabicText.hiddenTextarea.focus();` is not necessary any more.

Comment: But I can't see the caret, it's very inconvenient.

Comment: Using 1.7, the hiddenTextarea.focus() is done for you in enterEditing(), but I had to do `fabicText.selectAll(); fabicText.enterEditing();` in that order to get the selection to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, the only thing works

```
  Text.on('selected', function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Text.enterEditing();
      Text.hiddenTextarea.focus();
    }, 100);
  });
```